# JSON Schema - bq load errors

Tags: google-bigquery

This file is part json used:

```
{"body1": {"posts": {"children": [{"row": {"acceptedanswerid": "26", "answercount": "5", "body": "<p>Now that the Engineer update has come, there will be lots of Engineers building up everywhere.  How should this best be handled?</p>\n", "commentcount": "7", "creationdate": "2010-07-07T19:06:25.043", "id": "1", "lastactivitydate": "2010-08-27T22:38:43.840", "lasteditdate": "2010-08-27T22:38:43.840", "lasteditordisplayname": "", "lasteditoruserid": "56", "owneruserid": "11", "posttypeid": "1", "score": "10", "tags": "<strategy><team-fortress-2><tactics>", "title": "In Team Fortress 2, what is a good strategy to deal with lots of engineers turtling on the other team?", "viewcount": "1166"}}, {"row": {"acceptedanswerid": "184", "answercount": "3", "body": "<p>I know I can create a Warp Gate and teleport to Pylons, but I have no idea how to make Warp Prisms or know if there's any other unit capable of transporting.</p>\n\n<p>I would in particular like this to built remote bases in 1v1</p>\n", "commentcount": "2", "creationdate": "2010-07-07T19:07:58.427", "id": "2", "lastactivitydate": "2010-07-08T00:21:13.163", "lasteditdate": "2010-07-08T00:16:46.013", "lasteditordisplayname": "", "lasteditoruserid": "68", "owneruserid": "10", "posttypeid": "1", "score": "5", "tags": "<starcraft-2><how-to><protoss>", "title": "What protoss unit can transport others?", "viewcount": "398"}}]}}}
```

This is the schema used:

```
{
 "name":"body1", "type": "STRING",
 "name":"posts", "type": "STRING",  
 "name":"children", "type":"RECORD",
 "fields": [    
    {"name": "row", "type": "STRING"},
    {"name": "acceptedanswerid", "type": "STRING"},
    {"name": "answercount", "type": "STRING"},
    {"name": "body", "type": "STRING"},
    {"name": "commentcount", "type": "STRING"},
    {"name": "creationdate", "type": "STRING"},
    {"name": "id", "type": "string"},
    {"name": "lasteditdate", "type": "integer"},
    {"name": "lasteditordisplayname", "type": "string"},
    {"name": "lasteditoruserid", "type": "string"},
    {"name": "owneruserid", "type": "string"},
    {"name": "posttypeid", "type": "string"},
    {"name": "score", "type": "string"},
    {"name": "tags", "type": "string"},
    {"name": "title", "type": "string"},
    {"name": "viewcount", "type": "string"}
]
}
```

The problem is in the implementation of the scheme. But I didn't find the detailed scheme to build the model. Anyone can help me?

Following the suggestion of Gil, I modified your original design for this valid json:

```
{
"name":"body1", "type": "RECORD",
"fields": [
{"name":"posts", "type": "RECORD",
"fields": [
    {"name":"children", "type": "RECORD",
    "fields": [    
        {"name": "row", "type": "STRING"},
        {"name": "acceptedanswerid", "type": "STRING"},
        {"name": "answercount", "type": "STRING"},
        {"name": "body", "type": "STRING"},
        {"name": "commentcount", "type": "STRING"},
        {"name": "creationdate", "type": "STRING"},
        {"name": "id", "type": "string"},
        {"name": "lasteditdate", "type": "integer"},
        {"name": "lasteditordisplayname", "type": "string"},
        {"name": "lasteditoruserid", "type": "string"},
        {"name": "owneruserid", "type": "string"},
        {"name": "posttypeid", "type": "string"},
        {"name": "score", "type": "string"},
        {"name": "tags", "type": "string"},
        {"name": "title", "type": "string"},
        {"name": "viewcount", "type": "string"}
    ]}]}]}
```

The bq command return:

> - File: 0 / Offset:0 / Line:1 / Column:8 / Field:body1: no such field

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the raw data you've provided, it looks like "children" is a child of "posts", which in turn is a child of "body1" - meaning that everything is nested, and not 3 fields in the same hierarchy as you've described.

You should create your schema to reflect this, e.g. (not tested):

```
{
 "name":"body1", "type": "RECORD"
 "fields": [
    "name":"posts", "type": "RECORD"
    "fields": [
        "name":"children", "type": "RECORD"
        "fields": [    
            {"name": "row", "type": "STRING"},
            {"name": "acceptedanswerid", "type": "STRING"},
            {"name": "answercount", "type": "STRING"},
            {"name": "body", "type": "STRING"},
            {"name": "commentcount", "type": "STRING"},
            {"name": "creationdate", "type": "STRING"},
            {"name": "id", "type": "string"},
            {"name": "lasteditdate", "type": "integer"},
            {"name": "lasteditordisplayname", "type": "string"},
            {"name": "lasteditoruserid", "type": "string"},
            {"name": "owneruserid", "type": "string"},
            {"name": "posttypeid", "type": "string"},
            {"name": "score", "type": "string"},
            {"name": "tags", "type": "string"},
            {"name": "title", "type": "string"},
            {"name": "viewcount", "type": "string"}
        ]
     ]
 ]
}
```

**EDIT 1**

OK, I took your input example and ran it through a schema generator (https://github.com/tottokug/BigQuerySchemaGenerator), and it gave:

```
[
    {
        "name": "body1",
        "type": "RECORD",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "posts",
                "type": "RECORD",
                "fields": [
                    [
                        {
                            "name": "row",
                            "type": "RECORD",
                            "fields": [
                                {
                                    "name": "acceptedanswerid",
                                    "type": "STRING"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "answercount",
                                    "type": "STRING"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "body",
                                    "type": "STRING"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "commentcount",
                                    "type": "STRING"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "creationdate",
                                    "type": "STRING"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "id",
                                    "type": "STRING"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "lastactivitydate",
                                    "type": "STRING"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "lasteditdate",
                                    "type": "STRING"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "lasteditordisplayname",
                                    "type": "STRING"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "lasteditoruserid",
                                    "type": "STRING"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "owneruserid",
                                    "type": "STRING"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "posttypeid",
                                    "type": "STRING"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "score",
                                    "type": "STRING"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "tags",
                                    "type": "STRING"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "title",
                                    "type": "STRING"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "viewcount",
                                    "type": "STRING"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    [
                        {
                            "name": "row",
                            "type": "RECORD",
                            "fields": [
                                {
                                    "name": "acceptedanswerid",
                                    "type": "STRING"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "answercount",
                                    "type": "STRING"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "body",
                                    "type": "STRING"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "commentcount",
                                    "type": "STRING"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "creationdate",
                                    "type": "STRING"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "id",
                                    "type": "STRING"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "lastactivitydate",
                                    "type": "STRING"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "lasteditdate",
                                    "type": "STRING"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "lasteditordisplayname",
                                    "type": "STRING"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "lasteditoruserid",
                                    "type": "STRING"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "owneruserid",
                                    "type": "STRING"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "posttypeid",
                                    "type": "STRING"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "score",
                                    "type": "STRING"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "tags",
                                    "type": "STRING"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "title",
                                    "type": "STRING"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "viewcount",
                                    "type": "STRING"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Does this work?

Comment: Gil, I implemented this new scheme. They are definitely groupings. Anyway this scheme you sent me is not valid.I made some changes and transformed into valid with your initial design.But I still don't solve the problem.

Comment: This the command used: bq load --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON --schema=post_schema_6.json open_stack.posts_demo_25 tests.json 
this the error message with the new schema **BigQuery error in load operation: Field posts is type RECORD but has no schema